# From the given multiline string give the count of how many times the word ‘thought’ has occurred without using a built-in function

Tags: python, string

I have a multi-line string:

```py
Str1 = """I thought a thought.
But the thought I thought
Wasn’t the thought I thought I thought.
If the thought I thought I thought,
Had been the thought I thought ."""
```

From the given multiline string give the count of how many times the word ‘thought’ has occurred without using a built-in function

Comment: What do you mean without buildin function? So you can't use ```for``` either?

Comment: I counted 12 occurrances.

Comment: Without using any built-in function? So, `Str1.split()` is also not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's not difficult, just split up the string and count it:

```
s = """I thought a thought. But the thought I thought Wasn’t the thought I thought I thought. If the thought I thought I thought, Had been the thought I thought ."""

words = s.split()
count = 0
for word in words:
    if word.strip(',.') == 'thought': # remove dots and commers possibly preceding it
        count += 1
print(count)
# 12
```

Answer (score -2):

```
print(Str1.count('thought'))
```

that's all.

if you are planning to do something the word 'thought' you can use

```
count = 0
for n in Str1.split():
    if 'thought' in n:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: He said DON'T use built-in function

Comment: I added another solution that is not using any built-in functions.